# How to set 3 images on bootstrap left, center and right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

How to set 3 images on bootstrap left, center and right on same line

I tried that:

```
<div class="row">
  <img class="col-md-3 pull-right" src="images/right.png" alt="right">
  <img class="col-md-3 center-block" src="images/center.png" alt="center">
  <img class="col-md-3 pull-left" src="images/left.png" alt="left">
</di>
```

But the second image is not centered.

The right and left image, should be in the corner of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it what you want to achieve?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><img alt="" src="//placehold.it/200x200/c69/fff/?text=left"  class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img alt="" src="//placehold.it/200x200/9c6/fff/?text=center" class="img-responsive center-block"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img alt="" src="//placehold.it/200x200/69c/fff/?text=right"  class="img-responsive pull-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to give `col-md-4` to each img check out the sample. Run the code snippet and open it in a full page  to view properly.

**or**

Follow the link to view the sample: [*Sample Link*](https://codepen.io/parth7676/pen/rLRNNR)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<img class="col-md-4" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/a/a4/Google-Currents-Featured-300x300.png" alt="right">
  <img class="col-md-4" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/a/a4/Google-Currents-Featured-300x300.png" alt="center">
  <img class="col-md-4" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/a/a4/Google-Currents-Featured-300x300.png" alt="left">
```

Comment: this images is not in aligned at: LEFT------------CENTER--------------RIGHT.